# Struggling creating a simple list parser in TypeScript without any mutation

Tags: typescript, parsing, compilation, lisp, tokenize

I'm trying to write a very rudimentary lisp parser in TypeScript that turns a `string` (in this case the, the lisp code) into an syntax tree (nested arrays representing the parsed s-expressions) while avoiding any mutation.

Here's my progress so far:

```js
 // The lisp code used as input.
const input = "(+ 1 1 (+ 2 2) (+ 1 1))"
```

```js
// My tokenizer, which does the job fine.
function tokenizer(input: string): string[ {
  return input
    .replace(/\(/g, " ( ")
    .replace(/\)/g, " ) ")
    .trim()
    .split(/\s+/)
}
```

```js
// The parser, which doesn't work as expected.
function parser(tokens: string[], list: any[] = []): any[] {
  if (tokens.length == 0)
    return list

  const [head, ...tail] = tokens

  if (head === "(")
    return [...list, parser(tail)]

  if (head === ")")
    return list

  return parser(tail, [...list, head])
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to continue the parsing of the remaining tokens after the first parens gets closed.

For instance, the parser currently return `[ "+", "1", "1", [ "+", "2", "2" ] ]`.

I've tried recursing again through the remaining tokens on close, but that nests any further expressions inside the preceding one:

```js
function parser(tokens: string[], list: any[] = []): any[] {
  if (tokens.length == 0)
    return list

  const [head, ...tail] = tokens

  if (head === "(")
    return [...list, parser(tail)]

  if (head === ")")
    return parser(tail, list)

  return parser(tail, [...list, head])
}
```

Returns `[ "+", "1", "1", [ "+", "2", "2", [ "+", "1", "1" ] ] ]`

Any help at solving this would be very appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: try to write the parser so that it returns two values: the parsed form and the list of remaining tokens to parse (spoiler: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/50562146/124319)